# Проблема при компиляции проекта Unity

Tags: c#, android, unity3d

Возникла проблема при компиляции проекта в Unity под андройд. В какой-то момент компиляция проекта останавливается и консоль выводит следующие сообщения:

```
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details

> Configure project :launcher
WARNING: The option 'android.enableR8' is deprecated and should not be used anymore.
It will be removed in a future version of the Android Gradle plugin, and will no longer allow you to disable R8.

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not dispatch a message to the daemon.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.3.0f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.3.0f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-5.6.4.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleRelease"

stderr[

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not dispatch a message to the daemon.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
]
stdout[
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details

> Configure project :launcher
WARNING: The option 'android.enableR8' is deprecated and should not be used anymore.
It will be removed in a future version of the Android Gradle plugin, and will no longer allow you to disable R8.
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1[T] progress, System.String error) (at <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
Rethrow as BuildFailedException: Exception of type 'UnityEditor.Build.BuildFailedException' was thrown.
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.CancelPostProcess.AbortBuild (System.String title, System.String message, System.Exception ex) (at <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
```

```
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <50f55621a2ca4f31a35283e2979a8bf5>:0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)
```

```
Build completed with a result of 'Failed' in 237 seconds (237320 ms)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

```
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 4 errors
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x002ca] in <50f55621a2ca4f31a35283e2979a8bf5>:0 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in <50f55621a2ca4f31a35283e2979a8bf5>:0 
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Путь к вашему проекту содержит русские символы, их надо убрать.

Я бы рекомендовал создать папку в корне диска, и создавать все проекты там